# model hasMany Relation with where condition?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I can get all articles for each category with this code:

```
$category->article
```

Now I want to get all articles with some condition (in articles table)

I try this

```
$category->article->wherePublish(1)->
                    whereFeature('top')->latest()->
                    take(9)->get();
```

but I get this error:

> Method wherePublish does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$category->article` executes the query and you get a collection. Collections do not have `wherePublish` and similar magic methods, that's why you're getting the error.

If you want to filter articles, use this syntax:

```
Article::where('category_id', $category->id)
    ->wherePublish(1)
    ->whereFeature('top')
    ->latest()
    ->take(9)
    ->get();
```

This will work for `hasOne` and `hasMany` relationships. For `belongsToMany` use `whereHas()` method instead of `where()`.

Alternatively, you could define a separate relationship like:

```
public function filteredArticles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'article_id')
        ->wherePublish(1)
        ->whereFeature('top')
        ->latest()
        ->take(9);
}
```

And use it:

```
$category->filteredArticles
```